# Анаконда не устанавливается на Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia и windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь установить и начать обучение но при установке на win7(32bit) dont create menus или что то типо Ну и я как самый умный разбил диск и установил линукс минт 19.3 (64bit) Tricia но и там я не понимаю вообще установку прог ну ладно подумал может у меня старая версия python или еще что я скачал из менеджера прог и проверил версию последняя хорошо но все равно не чего не работает нет норм ответа ни в Google ни в яндексе нигде.

Comment: В линуксах в каждом по разному - к примеру в Минт это делается через `sudo apt-get install name progam` что говорит установить программу от имени `sudo` но это случится если программа есть в оф директории

Comment: [вот здесь всё расписано](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) в вашем случае это `Debian`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Anaconda не устанавливается на linux mint и Windows 7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078484/anaconda-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux-mint-%d0%b8-windows-7)

Comment: @РоманКот, не нужно повторять, достаточно одного вопроса. Вы задали предыдущий вопрос 5 часов назад, это примерно 3 часа ночи по Москве. Вы ожидали что в 3 часа ночи на него кто-то сразу что-то ответит?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, лучше тот вопрос закрыть как дубликат на этот, раз уж здесь начали комменты появляться.

Comment: Хорошо, пойду тот помечу, чтобы он раньше до очереди на закрытие добрался.